# Maximum value of $p$

Tags: probability

I need help with the following question:

A and B are two events such that $\Pr(A) = 3p$, $\Pr(B) = 2\sqrt(p)$, and $\Pr(A\cap B) = p$.
Find the maximum possible value for $p$.

Comment: Can you reason whether or not $p$ being maximized would imply that $\Pr(A\cup B)=1$?  Do you remember that $\Pr(A\cup B)=\Pr(A)+\Pr(B)-\Pr(A\cap B)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you cannot follow what @JMoravitz said, look here.

Let $Pr(A \cup B)=x$. Then, $x=3p+2√p-p=2p+2√p$.
This equation is quadratic in $√p$ and it reduces to
$p=\frac{1+x- \sqrt{1+2x}}{2}$.

Clearly, $p$ is an increasing function of $x$. This means the maximum value of $p$ will be attained when $x=1$. Hence the maximum value of $p=1- \frac{√3}{2}$

Comment: The answer you got matches the answer for that multiple-choice question I was doing. So it seems that we assume that for the maximum value p, Pr(A U B) = 1? It wasn't stated in the question

Comment: Yes for maximum value of $p$, Pr(A $\cup$ B) has to be 1. We have proved it.